# Javascript: toString(36) for large integers

Tags: javascript, integer, largenumber, radix

`15955067621307336078.toString(36);` returns `'3d7vzfy5k2as8'` in Javascript because the large integer cannot be represented (the correct answer is `'3d7vzfy5k29ou'`).

Does someone have a clever function that takes a large integer as a string and converts it to base 36?

Comment: @Cameron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Comment: Actually, I get `"3d7vzfy5k2a68"` for `15955067621307336078..toString(36)`

Comment: I tried writing my own base conversion function, but it stops working completely after a certain size. http://jsfiddle.net/SEZXq/1/

Comment: @Bergi - The largest int that JavaScript supports is 9007199254740992. You're number is over that, so the answer you get is determined by how the implementation misbehave when there is overflow. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/535871).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [this BigInt class](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js), which allows conversion of arbitrarily large integers to any arbitrary base between 2 and 95.  Use the `bigInt2str()` method to perform the conversion.

Comment: Thanks this worked great.
`bigInt2str(str2bigInt("15955067621307336078",10,0,0),36).toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious, today we are using https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js instead.